# The measure of a rotated 1-dimensional null set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu:\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}\to [0,\infty]$ be the Borel measure defined by $$ \nu(E) \:= \lambda_2\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \in E\} $$
Where $\lambda_2$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to show that $\nu \mathbin{<\!\!<} \lambda $, the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. I have one approach, and 3 questions that follow.

---

Suppose $\lambda(E) = 0$ and fix $\epsilon>0$. Take a cover of $E$ by open intervals such that 
    $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |I_k| < \epsilon $$

Define for convenience $A := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 \in E\}$, and $A_n := A \cap [-n,n]^2$.

I want to show that $\nu(A_n) = 0$ from which $\nu(A)=0$ follows by $\sigma$-continuity.

For a fixed $I_k$, we can construct a square centred at the same point as the original interval with twice(say) the width. We can then translate this square around the circle centred at $0$ which passes through this point so that each box contains at least $|I_k|$ of the circle. This is going to take at most $m:=\frac{2\pi n}{|I_k|}$ boxes; call these boxes $J_{i,k}$, then 
    $$ \sum_{i=1}^m \left|J_{i,k}\right| = m \cdot 4 |I_k|^2 = 8\pi n|I_k| $$
Thus we have a cover $\{J_{i,k}\}$ of $A_n$,  and $\sum_{i,k} |J_{i,k}| = 8\pi n \epsilon$
which can be made arbitrarily small, so $\nu(A_n) = 0$ and we are done.

---

Questions:

1. Is this correct (and rigourous)?
2. Is there an easier solution?
3. The exam question also asks for the Radon-Nikodym derivative $f = \frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$. By a picture, this feels like it should be $f(x) = 2\pi x$; is this even right and how do I justify this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it in polar coordinates:
$$ \nu(E) = \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} I_E(r) \, d\theta r \, dr = 2\pi \int_{E\cap [0,\infty)} r \, dr .$$
Done.  (Note $f(r) = 2\pi r I_{r \ge 0} $.)

Comment: Thank you. That was the motivation for what I did above but this was a question in a measure theory past paper which is a rigorous course and we didnt ever cover polar coordinates with respect to lebesegue integration. Is there a simple way to see this change which we know works with the Riemann integral works with lebesegue?

Comment: To establish the formula, it is sufficient to prove it for the case $E$ is an interval.  This is because the smallest sigma algebra containing intervals is the set of Borel sets.